# Shade Smooth not working in the render tab (even after recalculating/merging normals)

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

This weird flat shading is occurring on the curved surface even after shading smooth and merging normals.

It is a model exported from Rhino as an FBX

No modifiers applied.

Viewport shading and edit mode visuals are provided below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check for (and discard) custom normals first, in properties/object data/geometry data/clear custom split normals data.  Custom normals will replace smooth shaded normals.  If using autosmooth, make sure your angle is sufficient-- just set it to 180.

Comment: @Nathan Tried that. Looks like it still didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include more details, images about the object, what modifiers it has, if it has custom data, if it was imported from another software, etc...

Comment: Supply the blend file and I'll look.

Comment: Maybe mesh object has all edges marked as sharp after importing. Clear sharp operator in Edit mode is for that. Note also to include screenshots of the geometry itself, not only resulting render as it requires others to guess

Answer (score 1):

You need more subdivisions on the object to appear curved.

Here's an object only with smooth shading (rendered image on the right), note that the edges and faces are visible.

[image]

Here's the same object with smooth shading and a subdivision surface modifier. The curves are smooth.

[image]

Just for comparison, here's the same object with flat shading. Compare to smooth shading only.

[image]

Click on the images to show enlarged in full screen.

Comment: It is an FBX imported from Rhino, SS is going to ruin the surface.