# Edges looks sharp in smooth mesh

Tags: mesh

Why do I see edges in my object? It is smooth, has enough vertices , has Edge Split Modifier.And shading is set to "Smooth"
Any idea please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9SEM.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably obvious, but always good first things to do is make sure to check for/clean up any dupes (M > By Distance), and recalculate normals (Edit mode > Select al > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208676/92768